# Desactivating a setinterval function?

Tags: console, setinterval, console.log

I have absolutely no idea why, but on 2 websites (2 websites that I professionnaly work on, and they havent been hacked or compromised), my Chrome console keeps clearing every 500ms.
Which is pretty annoying.
I desactivated all extensions. Tried private browsing. It's the same thing.
I uninstalled chrome as well as my extensions. Same.

When I try to reproduce it on someone else's computer, I cannot.
When I use another Chrome session the issue does not happen.

I have absolutely no idea how to get rid of this or what is the exact cause of the issue.

The code running is :

```
setInterval(function(){console.clear();console.info('Console was cleared by browser extension.');},500);
```

Since I unfortunately do not seem to find the reason, my only question will be : would there be a way to desactivate that code or postpone the setinveral to a bigger number?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, on the developer tools, click on the settings icon, and tick the the "Preserve Log" option so the console is not cleared.

If your websites happen to be ecommerce (Magento specially) I'll advice you to check your code well for unknown js. This is one of the "symptoms" of the Magecart credit card skimmer. [Preserve log option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmqOF.png)